# Created extra columns from list

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a list which contains unique strings from two different pandas columns, A and B.
For example:

```
A          B
aaa      asd
sad      aaa
vas      aaa
wow      kid
asd      vas

list_a=df.A.unique().tolist()
list_b=df.B.unique().tolist()

list_ab=list(set(list_a+list_b))
```

`list_ab` contains therefore `aaa, sad, vas, wow, asd, kid`.

I am manually assigning values for each element in `list_ab`, so I am creating a new list with these values:

```
list_values=[7.5, 2.0, 1.5, 3.6, 7.4, 8.2]
```

I need to create a new column in the dataset where I assign the average of the values of the elements in `A` and `B`; so

```
    A          B    A_val       B_val     Value
    aaa      asd     7.5          7.4      7.45
    sad      aaa     2.0          7.5      4.75
    vas      aaa     1.5          7.5      4.5
    wow      kid     3.6          8.2      5.9
    asd      vas     7.4          1.5      4.45
```

I don't know how to create the two columns `A_val` and `B_val` in order to have the corresponding values for `A` and `B` elements. Should I merge, join?

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = {list_ab[i]: list_values[i] for i in range(len(list_ab))}#Create dictionary


#Map dictionary values to create new columns 
df=df.assign(A_val=df['A'].map(res),B_val=df['B'].map(res),Value=df.filter(like='_val').mean(1))



    A    B    A_val  B_val  Value
0  aaa  asd    1.5    7.4   4.45
1  sad  aaa    8.2    1.5   4.85
2  vas  aaa    3.6    1.5   2.55
3  wow  kid    2.0    7.5   4.75
4  asd  vas    7.4    3.6   5.50
```

Answer (score 1):

For the additional columns try `replace`

```
out = df.join(df.replace(dict(zip(df.melt().value.unique(),list_values))).add_suffix('_value'))
Out[147]: 
     A    B  A_value  B_value
0  aaa  asd      7.5      7.4
1  sad  aaa      2.0      7.5
2  vas  aaa      1.5      7.5
3  wow  kid      3.6      8.2
4  asd  vas      7.4      1.5
```

Then

```
out['Value'] = out.filter(like='value').mean(1)
out
Out[153]: 
     A    B  A_value  B_value  Value
0  aaa  asd      7.5      7.4   7.45
1  sad  aaa      2.0      7.5   4.75
2  vas  aaa      1.5      7.5   4.50
3  wow  kid      3.6      8.2   5.90
4  asd  vas      7.4      1.5   4.45
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it using `merge` :

```
df_A_val = pd.DataFrame(A_val, index = A, columns = ['A_value'])
df_B_val = pd.DataFrame(B_val, index = B, columns = ['B_value'])


df = df.merge(df_A_val, right_index = True, left_on = 'A')
df = df.merge(df_B_val, right_index = True, left_on = 'B')

df['Value'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].T.mean()

df.drop_duplicates()
```

The result of `df` should be something like:

```
     A    B  A_value  B_value  Value
0  aaa  asd      7.5      7.4   7.45
1  sad  aaa      2.0      7.5   4.75
2  vas  aaa      1.5      7.5   4.50
3  wow  kid      3.6      8.2   5.90
4  asd  vas      7.4      1.5   4.45
```

Of course that if you want to add more columns a little adjustments would be needed in the code.